# Clustering with DBSCAN in matlab

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, dbscan

i am trying to cluster a 3d binary matrix (size: 150x131x134) because there are separeted groups of data structure.
i used kmeans(X) before and in some cases there is a good output, but only for data sets which contain less than 4 cluster structures. my matrix will contain up to 8 separate data structures and the kmeans is unefficient then because there is a high dependence on inital conditions in some cases it cuts a data structure in half.
now i found another cluster algorithm: dbscan
but i couldnt find any implementation which works in 3d in matlab too.

any idea where i can get a good dbscan algorithm implementation in matlab?

Comment: Might be of your interest....http://yaikhom.com/2015/12/29/image-segmentaion-using-dbscan-clustering.html